# Dynamic detection of boundry box:The Python script for image cropping based on annotation files fails to accurately capture the defined bounding boxes

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have annotated images and aim to load and crop them based on the boundary box information provided in a text file. Despite my code implementation, I'm encountering inaccuracies in identifying the image boundaries.

Assistance in resolving this issue would be appreciated.

My code is:

```
   import os
import cv2

def crop_image_with_annotation(image_path, annotation_path, output_folder):
    # Read image
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    print(f"Image loaded: {image_path}")

    if img is None:
        print(f"Error: Could not read image {image_path}")
        return

    # Read bounding box coordinates from annotation file
    with open(annotation_path, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline().strip()
        print("Annotation line:", line)

        # Split the line into values
        values = line.split()

        # Check if the line contains the class label
        if len(values) == 5:
            class_label, x_center, y_center, width, height = map(float, values)
            print("Found class label:", class_label)
        elif len(values) == 4:
            x_center, y_center, width, height = map(float, values)
        else:
            print("Invalid annotation format")
            return

    # Convert normalized coordinates to pixel coordinates
    img_height, img_width = img.shape[:2]

    print(f"Image height: {img_height}, Image width: {img_width}")

    x_center = int(x_center * img_width)
    y_center = int(y_center * img_height)
    half_width = int(width * img_width / 2)
    half_height = int(height * img_height / 2)

    # Calculate bounding box coordinates
    x1 = max(0, x_center - half_width)
    y1 = max(0, y_center - half_height)
    x2 = min(img_width, x_center + half_width)
    y2 = min(img_height, y_center + half_height)

    # Print calculated crop coordinates
    print(f"Calculated crop coordinates: (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = ({x1}, {y1}), ({x2}, {y2})")

    # Crop image based on bounding box coordinates
    cropped_img = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    # Save cropped image to output folder
    filename = os.path.basename(image_path)
    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)
    cv2.imwrite(output_path, cropped_img)
    print(f"Cropped image saved: {output_path}")


# Define input and output folders
input_folder = r"C:\Users\Desktop\crop"
output_folder = r"C:\Users\Desktop\crop\new"

# Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Iterate over files in the input folder
for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".jpeg"):  # Check if the file is an image
        # Construct paths for image and annotation file
        image_path = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
        annotation_path = os.path.join(input_folder, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".txt")

        # Check if the annotation file exists
        if not os.path.exists(annotation_path):
            print(f"Annotation file not found for image {filename}. Skipping...")
            continue

        # Crop image based on annotation
        crop_image_with_annotation(image_path, annotation_path, output_folder)
```

My input file is on desktop in folder crop in `jpg` format:

Output cropped image is :

While i want to read whole num plate :

My annotation file in .txt formate is has values::

```
0 0.5247395833333334 0.687037037037037 0.06822916666666666 0.04814814814814815
```

The other images are :: for this my .txt file is

```
3 0.20859375 0.7708333333333334 0.37447916666666664 0.44722222222222224
2 0.55 0.711574074074074 0.20520833333333333 0.5601851851851852
2 0.7627604166666667 0.7435185185185185 0.17239583333333333 0.5055555555555555
1 0.5692708333333333 0.9523148148148148 0.034375 0.05092592592592592
```

Now my code output is:

I need two bikes and their helmets to be detected as well.

My expected output is

Comment: I believe at least one image and one annotation file containing one onnnotated imge should be provided to allow a wide audience of SO users to try to help you

Comment: welcome. [mre] required. people can't give you solutions to *your specific issue* if you make it impossible to *reproduce your issue*.

Comment: I provided the input image file and output image after cropping the file with my code.

Comment: unfortunately, you removed those pictures that helped me figure out your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say where those annotations come from or what the numbers mean specifically.

They appear to be ***center point*** and size, ***not*** "top left corner, bottom right corner".

You need to subtract half width and height from the center for the one corner and add half width and height for the other corner.

Comment: Yes, it worked for reading the number plate area. Now, the other problem is I want my code to be dynamic enough to handle all images with one class or more classes (bounding boxes) within my code. I am adding the image to my question.

Comment: Thatv would need to  be another questoon as per SO policy

Answer (score 0):

ok took a while , `input.png` in `inp` folder toghether with `annotation.txt`:

`input.png` :

[image]

`annotation.txt`:

```
1 238 230 180 178
```

with code:

```
import os
import cv2
def crop_image_with_annotation(image_path, annotation_path, output_folder):
    # Read image
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    # Read bounding box coordinates from annotation file
    with open(annotation_path, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline().strip()
        print("Annotation line:", line)  # Debugging line
        print("Image saved:",)
        # Split the line into values
        values = line.split()
        # Check if the line contains the class label
        if len(values) == 5:
            class_label, x_min, y_min, width, height = map(float, values)
            
            print('class_label, x_min, y_min, width, height :' , class_label, x_min, y_min, width, height)
            
        elif len(values) == 4:
            x_min, y_min, width, height = map(float, values)
        else:
            print("Invalid annotation format")
            return
    # Convert normalized coordinates to pixel coordinates
    img_height, img_width = img.shape[:2]
    x1 = int(x_min )
    
    print('x1 : ' , x1)
    
    y1 = int(y_min )
    
    print('y1 : ', y1)
        
    x2 = int((x_min + width))
    y2 = int((y_min + height))
    
    
    # Crop image based on bounding box coordinates
    cropped_img = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    # Save cropped image to output folder
    filename = os.path.basename(image_path)
    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder,'output_'+filename)
    cv2.imwrite(output_path, cropped_img)
    
    print('-->' ,filename , output_path)
    
    
# Define input and output folders
input_folder = "inp"
output_folder = "out"



# Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)



# Iterate over files in the input folder
for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):  # Check if the file is an image
        # Construct paths for image and annotation file
        image_path = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
        
        print('image_path : ', image_path)
        # annotation_path = os.path.join(input_folder, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".txt")
        
        annotation_path = os.path.join(input_folder, "annotation.txt")
        
        # Check if the annotation file exists
        if not os.path.exists(annotation_path):
            print(f"Annotation file not found for image {filename}. Skipping...")
            continue
        # Crop image based on annotation
        crop_image_with_annotation(image_path, annotation_path, output_folder)
```

I get in `out` folder file `output_input.png` :

[image]

So I guess the problem was about the relation between  `annotation.txt` vs coords in here :

```
# Convert normalized coordinates to pixel coordinates
    img_height, img_width = img.shape[:2]
    x1 = int(x_min )
    
    print('x1 : ' , x1)
    
    y1 = int(y_min )
    
    print('y1 : ', y1)
        
    x2 = int((x_min + width))
    y2 = int((y_min + height))
```

Or it could have been , `annotation.txt` :

```
1 0.264 0.365 0.2 0.284
```

with coords translation:

```
 # Convert normalized coordinates to pixel coordinates
    img_height, img_width = img.shape[:2]
    
    print('image : img_height, img_width : ', img_height, img_width)
    
    x1 = int(x_min*img_width )
    
    print('x1 : ' , x1)
    
    y1 = int(y_min*img_height)
    
    print('y1 : ', y1)
        
    x2 = int((x1 + width*img_width))
    
    print('x2 : ' , x2)
    
    y2 = int(y1 + height*img_height)
    
    print('y2 : ', y2)
```

that should be equal to your:

```
 x1 = int(x_min * img_width)
    
    y1 = int(y_min * img_height)
    
    x2 = int((x_min + width) * img_width)
    
    y2 = int((y_min + height) * img_height)
```

output :

[image]

but without an input we could hardly tell